# Issue running Hive on spark with Hive table view mapping with Hbase table : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hbase, hiveql

I am trying to access Hbase table by mapping it from hive through spark engine.

### From Hive:

When I run the query on Hive view mapped with Hbase I could get all the desired result.

### From Spark:

When i run query to fetch from hive table ,i could get it but when i do the same for hbase mapped hive table i get below error.

```
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.initSerdeParams(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/lazy/LazySimpleSerDe$SerDeParameters; (state=,code=0)
```

I like to know whether it is possible to do it through spark as I did not find any solutions from internet.

From the above error I could figure that this is some jar issue and this method exists in hive-serde jar and hive-exec jar,but tried with all possible alternative but could not succeed..

Can any one help on this..

Note:My main objective here to check the performance as it is taking good amount of time in hive and pig as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which versions of software you are using hive, hbase & spark ...

***Seems like this is version mismatch issue.***

[Spark 1.3.1 uses Hive 0.13 API, while Spark 1.5.1 uses Hive 1.2, hbase serde that comes with hive 2.3 is not compatible with Hive 0.13 API.
I tried with old Serde for Hive 0.13, but there are lots of conflicts with Hbase API versions.](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/4838/javalangnosuchmethoderror-orgapachehadoophiveserde.html)

- Depending on your need, you can try `Spark+Hbase` native integration instead of `Hive-Hbase Serde`.
- Or You can use correct compatible versions of hive.

#### Also have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12406 can be the same issue...

Comment: Thanks Ram,I will look into your sugestion for Spark+Hbse integrartion..The versions that i am using is 
HIve:1.2.1
Hbase:0.98
spark:2.0
hadoop:2.7.2
 In  hive-serde-1.2 version ,this method is not there....